# Onclick of images add and remove class to multiple Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have four colors shown as radio button with images. If a color image is clicked I am trying to grab the color image id and add it as class to multiple div elements.

It is working but it just adds classes of each and every image ( basically appending) whenever a image is clicked, what I am trying to is if the a image is clicked only add the id of that image as class and if one more image is clicked, remove the existing image class and the new one.

here is my code

HTML

```
<ul id="thumbnails1" class="noul swatch-colors">
<li><label class="lbswatches"><input class="rcolor" name="swatch_color" value="Cherry Red" type="radio"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/mZnrqa/g500_antique_cherry_red_color.jpg" id="CherryRed" class="full swatch-img" alt="Cherry Red" title="Cherry Red" width="32" height="32"></label></li>
<li><label class="lbswatches"><input class="rcolor" name="swatch_color"  value="Irish Green" type="radio"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/cuJLiv/g500_antique_irish_green_color.jpg" id="IrishGreen" class="full swatch-img" alt="Irish Green" title="Irish Green" width="32" height="32"></label></li>
<li><label class="lbswatches"><input class="rcolor" name="swatch_color" value="Jade Dome" type="radio"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/eVABqa/g500_antique_jade_dome_color.jpg" id="JadeDome" class="full swatch-img" alt="Jade Dome" title="Jade Dome" width="32" height="32"></label></li>
<li><label class="lbswatches"><input class="rcolor" name="swatch_color" value="Orange" type="radio"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/jGR6Ov/g500_antique_orange_color.jpg" id="Orange" class="full swatch-img" alt="Orange" title="Orange" width="32" height="32"></label></li>
</ul>
<h2 id="colorselected"></h2>
<br /><br /><br />
<div class="adult-section-box">
 <div class="pc-row">
 <ul class="quote-sizes adult-sizes noul pc-col">
<li><label><span>Adult Small</span><input id="adult_s" type="text" name="adult_s" data-var="adult_s" class="amtbox" placeholder="quanity" /></label></li>
      <li><label><span>Adult Medium</span><input id="adult_m" type="text" name="adult_m" data-var="adult_m" class="amtbox" placeholder="quanity" /></label></li>
      <li><label><span>Adult Large</span><input id="adult_l" type="text" name="adult_l" data-var="adult_l" class="amtbox" placeholder="quanity" /></label></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
<br /><br /><br />
<div class="youth-section-box">
 <div class="pc-row">
 <ul class="quote-sizes youth-sizes noul pc-col">
 <li><label><span>Youth X Small</span><input id="youth_xs" type="text" name="youth_xs" data-var="youth_xs" class="amtbox" placeholder="quanity" /></label></li>
      <li><label><span>Youth Small</span><input id="youth_s" type="text" name="youth_s" data-var="youth_s" class="amtbox" placeholder="quanity" /></label></li>
      <li><label><span>Youth Medium</span><input id="youth_m" type="text" name="youth_m" data-var="youth_m" class="amtbox" placeholder="quanity" /></label></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
```

jQuery

```
document.querySelectorAll('[name=swatch_color]')[0].checked = true;
    $('#thumbnails1').delegate('img','click', function(){
         $(this).closest('ul').find('.rcolor').attr('checked',false);
       $(this).prev().attr('checked',true);
       $("#colorselected").val($(this).attr("alt"));
       var imgid = this.id;
        $(".adult-section-box .pc-row, .youth-section-box .pc-row").addClass(imgid);           
   });
```

here is my [jFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pepin/zebhas3d/)

Thanks

Comment: the reason of add the image id, is because certain color does not come in youths or adult, so when a color is selected I am trying to hide adult or youth section which does not come in that color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset all these things using [`jQuery#attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) attribute of div.

```
    $(".full.swatch-img").on('click',function(){

        let colorCode = $(this).attr('id');

        $(".adult-section-box .pc-row, .youth-section-box .pc-row")
        .attr('class',colorCode+" pc-row");

    })
```

Updated [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/2kpohgur/)

Comment: This seems to work but any way to keep the parent reference class in tact so in this case I want to keep .adult-section-box and .youth-section-box be there all the time. Or should I change the parent classes to ID. Thanks

Comment: Yup changing parent classes to ID works great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
.addClass(imgid)
```

you could use

```
.attr("class",imgid);
```

This will overwrite the class attribute of the element.
So in your case, you want:

```
$(".adult-section-box .pc-row, .youth-section-box .pc-row").attr("class",imgid);
```

Comment: hmm this won't work as its removing the 2 reference classes when a color is clicked, and when one more color is clicked nothing happens as the reference classes no longer exists